# Where to find Wool on the ground?

Tags: palworld

Thinking about a pacifist and merchant-less run, I found one roll of Wool in the not-Hot places east of the Ancient Civilization Ruins.

But I've been there **4** times and only seen it once, in one spot. Is it really rare? Are there other places I can go to raise my chances of getting floor Wool?

I found another near the cage base near the Forgotten Island Church Ruins.

Anywhere else? Other than near the Alpha Sweepa of Small Cove Island?